# Queue Android Gatt operations

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I made a app the connects to a ble device and receives data from  it.  I was following this link "http://toastdroid.com/2014/09/22/android-bluetooth-low-energy-tutorial" at the Hints and observation section it says to Queue All GATT operations. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Check out NordicSemiconductors open source project [Puck Central](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/puck-central-android), or more specifically the [GattManager class](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/puck-central-android/blob/master/PuckCentral/app/src/main/java/no/nordicsemi/puckcentral/bluetooth/gatt/GattManager.java), who perfectly demonstrates how to queue all GATT operations.

If you don't want to handle this sort low level bluetooth specifics yourself however, I can recommend the great library [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle), which does much of the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 2):

To queue the requests you could make a queue class which has an Arraylist of requests.

Every time you want to make a request add it to the queue and start processing the queue (if the queue isn't already being processed). Once you've processed the current item check if there are still items to process and carry on processing them.

You'll also probably need to add a timeout in case one of the requests gets stuck.

Sample code on how you could process a queue using a handler:

```
private void startProcessingQueue() {
    if (queueIsRunning) {
        return;
    }

    queueIsRunning = true;
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            processQueue();

            if(queue.isEmpty()) {
                queueIsRunning = false;
                return;
            }

            h.postDelayed(this, QUEUE_PROCESSING_DELAY);
        }
    }, QUEUE_PROCESSING_DELAY);
}
```